# java SSLEngine wrap not reading all my data from buffer

Tags: java, ssl

I encountered this exception occuring

```
    SSLEngineResult result = sslEngine.wrap(b, engineToSocketData);
    if(b.hasRemaining())
        throw new RuntimeException(id+"Bug, should read all my data every time");
```

I have only seen it happen once and not sure how to reproduce it but why would java's SSLEngine not read all of the data from the ByteBuffer b in the above code?  I looked at the decompiled code of SSLEngine and SSLEngineImpl but I don't see anywhere obvious that this would occur.  Any ideas?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, dumb question since result has a status you can get that can return buffer overflow, underflow, etc. etc.

Comment: I wrote an api that makes using SSLEngine easier - http://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/sslfacade